# Nested Arrays and returning non-labeled values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an API that returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "columns": [
      "epoch_timestamp_millieseconds", 
      "cpu_used_percent"
    ], 
    "values": [
      [
        1615230210000, 
        28.24
      ],
...
```

I'm able to get the second metric using the following three lines of code:

```
<#assign metricvalue = jsonObj.data.values[0]>
<#assign arr = metricvalue[1]>
&value=${arr}
```

&value would equal 28.24.

Is there a way to combine these into one line of code?
I'm looking for something like this:
`&value=jsonObj.data.values[0].[1]`
The issue is the `[1]` doesn't have a label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. Just a small correction. Remove the `.` between `[0]` and `[1]`. You don't need to use `.` to specify the index. You only need to use it to specify the `property/key`.

**The code should be like**

```
jsonObj.data.values[0][0] // 1615230210000
jsonObj.data.values[0][1] // 28.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You were *very* close. Just remove the dot:

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "columns": [
      "epoch_timestamp_millieseconds",
      "cpu_used_percent"
    ],
    "values": [
      [
        1615230210000,
        28.24
      ]
    ]
  }
};

console.log(response.data.values[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring as well:

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "columns": [
      "epoch_timestamp_millieseconds", 
      "cpu_used_percent"
    ], 
    "values": [
      [
        1615230210000, 
        28.24
      ]
    ]
  }
};

const { data: { values: [[_, target]] } } = response;

console.log(target)
```